# Given that $\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{2}$ and $|x| < \frac{1}{8}$ find an upper bound for the magnitude of the error in the approximation

Tags: real-analysis

> Given that $\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{2}$ and $|x| < \frac{1}{8}$ find an upper bound for the magnitude of the error in the approximation

We have 
$$f(x)= (1+x)^{1/2} $$
$$f'(x) =  \frac{1}{2} (1+x)^{-1/2} $$
$$f''(x) = -\frac{1}{4(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}  $$

As $|x| < \frac{1}{8}$, we center about the mid-point $0$, so $x_0 =0$

$$f(x) = T_1 (x) + R_1 (x)$$
$$f(x) = 1 + \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{8(1+c)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$
Where $c$ is between $x$ and the center point $0$.

Now the objective if to determine a value bounding $R(x)=-\frac{x^2}{8(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $, starting with 
$$|c|<|x|<\frac{1}{8}$$
$$  \frac{x^2}{8(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}  < \frac{x^2}{8(1+x)^2} <|x|<\frac{1}{8} $$
$$  \frac{x^2}{8(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}} < \frac{x^2}{8(1+x)^2} < \frac{{(\frac{1}{8}})^2}{8(1+{\frac{1}{8}})^2} < {\frac{1}{8}} $$
$$\frac{x^2}{8(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}} < \frac{x^2}{8(1+x)^2} < \frac{1}{648}$$

Hence 
$$ |R(x)| < \frac{1}{648}$$

The last part is incorrect, i am trying different alternative with no success . how can I proceed the approach above?
Much appreciated.

Comment: It's not true that $\frac{x^2}{8(1+x)^{3/2}}<\frac{x^2}{8(1+x)^2}$. When $x>0$ the inequality is in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0<x<1/8 \implies 0<c<x<1/8$ $\implies 1<1+c\implies$ $ 0>-x^2\cdot8^{-1}(1+c)^{-3/2}>-x^2\cdot8^{-1}>-8^{-3}.$

$x=0$ is a trivial case with an error of $0.$

$-1/8<x<0\implies$ $-1/8<x<c<0 \implies$ $ 1+c>1+x>7/8 \implies$ $ 0>-x^2\cdot 8^{-1}(1+c)^{-3/2}>$ $8^{-3}(7/8)^{-3/2}=$ $-8^{-3}(8/7)^{3/2}.$

Comment: thx for the input. I am puzzled with another problem very similar with 2 different answers. Would you mind to take a look? I am trying again to figure out this bounding procedure using the approach you use. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2366517/find-an-upper-bound-for-the-magnitude-of-the-error-in-the-approximation-sinx

Comment: I added an A to that one. The other  2 answers are not incorrect but only in the sense that if |E|<1 then it is not incorrect to say |E|<10.

Comment: We have $\sqrt {1+x}\;<1+x/2$ for $-1<x$. A less well-known one  is that when $-1<x$ we have $\sqrt {1+x}\;>1+x/(2+x).$

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f=1+\frac{x}{2}-\sqrt{1+x}$$
has a positive second derivative, so it is convex, it attains its minimum at $ x=0$ so it is  nonnegative on the considered interval, hence
$$\sup \left\{f(x)|-\frac18< x<\frac18\right\}=\max\left(f(-\frac18),f(\frac18)\right)=\frac{15-4\sqrt{14}}{16}\approx 0.0020856533$$

Comment: What $f(x)$ is implied here?

Comment: @gegu, it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly:

$$\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{x} (t-x)(1+t)^{-\frac{3}{2}} dt$$

If $|t|<\frac{1}{8}$ then because $(1+t)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ is decreasing for $t \geq -1$, we have $\frac{16\sqrt{2}}{27} < (1+t)^{-\frac{3}{2}} < \frac{16\sqrt{14}}{49}$.

That means,

$$\frac{16\sqrt{2}}{27}(t-x) > (1+t)^{-\frac{3}{2}}(t-x)> (t-x) \frac{16\sqrt{14}}{49}$$

For all $x>t \geq 0$. The inequality reverses if $x<t \leq 0$.

For $\frac{1}{8}>x >0$, Integrating we find,

$$-\frac{16\sqrt{2}}{216}x^2> R_2(x) > - \frac{16\sqrt{14}}{392} x^2$$

That gives an upper bound of $0$ and lower bound of $-\frac{16\sqrt{14}}{25088}$. Now examine $-\frac{1}{8}<x<0$, you should get the same thing.

---

In such example it might even be easier to consider the extreme values of $e(x)=\sqrt{1+x}-(1+\frac{1}{2}x)$ directly  because there are so few terms.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$d(x)
=1+x/2-\sqrt{1+x}
$.
Then $d(x) > 0$
for $x > 0$
(since
$(1+x/2)^2
=1+x+x^2/4
$).

Doing the usual square root fiddling,
$d(x)(1+x/2+\sqrt{1+x})
=(1+x/2)^2-(1+x)
=x^2/4
$
so
$d(x)
=\dfrac{x^2/4}{1+x/2+\sqrt{1+x}}
\lt\dfrac{x^2/4}{2+x/2}
=\dfrac{x^2}{8+2x}
\lt\dfrac{x^2}{8}
$.

If
$|x| \le \frac18$,
$d(x)
\lt \frac1{512}
$.